# Split each column in dataframe into a vector and write to directory R

Tags: r, dataframe

Probably a trivial task, however, I cannot get it right.

I have a `data.frame` with 200,000 columns. The intention is to split these 200,000 separate columns into 200,000 column vectors and write each vector to directory using `write.csv`. The names of the `.csv` files should be the same as the colname in the `data.frame`.

**Sample:**

```
N=10
obs=data.frame(replicate(10,runif(100)))
n = paste0("col", 1:N); colnames(obs) = n
```

Any help on how to split the columns and write file is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:ncol(obs)) {
  write.csv(obs[,i, drop = F], paste0('PATH/', names(obs)[i], '.csv'))
}
```

Change the `PATH` part to your desired directory. Alternatively, you can `setwd('PATH')` and remove the first part in the `paste0`

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i in 1:ncol(obs)){
  colname <- names(obs)[i]
  write.csv(obs[,i], paste0(colname, ".csv"))
}
```

Comment: fine solution, but just be aware the column name in each dataframe will be `x`. In my solution, the column names will be preserved in the csv file